# Batch- Does MKDIR skip over a folder if it already exists and move onto the next one?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mkdir, steam

I am trying to create a Batch file that creates a series of folders in an already-existing directory.
If part of the directory already exists, will MKDIR skip over that one and continue down the directory or will it overwrite it?

A sample code is here:

```
mkdir %cdriveletter%\Steam\SteamApps\common\Counter-Strike Source\cstrike\custom\my_custom_skins\
```

In that code I want to only create the MyCustomSkins folder but it has to be in that directory. I do not want it to overwrite the stuff before it.

Will this suffice?

Comment: `mkdir` never deletes any "stuff"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mkdir` command will create any folders that do not exist in the specified path, unless extensions are disabled (`setLocal enableExtensions`) - regardless, it will not destroy a directory and create a new one with the same name.

See `mkdir /?` -

```
...

MKDIR creates any intermediate directories in the path, if needed.
For example, assume \a does not exist then:

    mkdir \a\b\c\d

is the same as:

    mkdir \a
    chdir \a
    mkdir b
    chdir b
    mkdir c
    chdir c
    mkdir d

which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled.
```

You should probably also surround your path with quotation marks.

Note: You could test that yourself, by creating some 'test' directories, and writing a similar command.

Comment: "which is what you would have to type if extensions were disabled" - you may want to clarify your first sentence in light of this.